# Is substituting $f(x)$ for the original function a valid process in algebra?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm referring to the general (non-abstract) algebraic case.

Suppose you start with something such as $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$, and upon algebraic manipulation during solving for $x,$ you arrange it such that $f(x)$ occurs in multiple places on one side of the equation and it just happens to look like it would be easier to solve, like

$f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2-1}$
$$1/2(2 f(x) + 1) ± 1/2 \sqrt{4 f(x) + 1}=1/2 (2 x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + 1) + 1/2 \sqrt{4 x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + 1}$$
$$1/2(2 f(x) + 1) ± 1/2 \sqrt{4 x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + 1}=1/2 (2 x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + 1) + 1/2 \sqrt{4 x + \sqrt{x^2 - 1} + 1}$$
and then solve for $x?$

Comment: Is y = f(x)? If so, yes, and I don't understand your doubt. If not, no, and I still do not understand your question.

Comment: It's pretty simple. Lets say you try to solve y=x^2 for x. Well, if you say y=x^2=x^2, and you arrange then equation into x^2=x^2, you can no longer solve for y because there's no y.

Comment: $y$ is not necessarily the same thing all the time as $f(x)$... but in terms of substitutions, supposing $a=b$ then it follows that $f(a)=f(b)$ for any function $f$... that is to say you can replace things with what they are equal and maintain truth.  The reverse however is not necessarily true.  $f(a)=f(b)$ does not imply that $a=b$.  In your example, $y=x^2$ and if you replace $y$ with $x^2$ you arrive at $x^2=x^2$... by subtracting $x^2$ from each side, you arrive at $0=0$... which is of course true.  In doing so, you do wind up losing some information however, so might not be useful

Comment: @JMoravitz So if I have something like $y=x+sin(x)$, and I arrange it such that $y-tan(y)=x^2$, it is completely valid to do something like $$y=x+sin(x)$$ -> $$y-tan(y)=x^2$$ $$y=x^2+tan(y)$$ $$y=x^2+tan(x+sin(x))$$? So in other words, you are saying with 100% certainty, that as long as $y$ appears in multiple places when solving for x, that it is completely valid to back-substitute y for the original function in only one instance of y and then solve for x and avoid the 0=0 reduction?

Comment: If you were to suppose that $y=x+\sin(x)$ and $y-\tan(y)=x^2$ are both true, then yes that does imply that $y=x^2+\tan(x+\sin(x))$ is true.  This can be helpful in narrowing your search for a specific solution set., however the reverse implication is not necessarily true.  It is not true that every $(x,y)$ pair that satisfies the third equality will satisfy both of the first two.  Remember again what I said, $a=b\implies f(a)=f(b)$ but the reverse $f(a)=f(b)$ does not imply $a=b$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Okay I will keep that in mind, thanks.